# github: Access rights and repository exist issue

Tags: git, github

i am new to using visual studio code, so after connecting my github to my Vscode and i try to make my first commit through the terminal i encountered this error :

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

i went to Git_hub to create SSH keys but it is not resolving the problem, i have try to connect the SSH keys in the terminal but all to no avail

Comment: What OS are you running on? What did you do to setup the SSH key that is not working?

Comment: i am using linux

Comment: i generated a new ssh on my github according to a tutorial i watched

Comment: I meant: what commands did you run, what did you set up on GitHub.. share the exact steps and commands. Otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: At the moment i have deleted everything, i have not set anything up, as nothing works and i do not want to conplicate things any further

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score -1):

so this is how i resolve this issue
step 1 :  `ls -al ~/.ssh`  #this will check if you have ssh key
Step 2 : `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`   #To generate a new SSH key, Replace the email address with the one associated with your GitHub account.
Step 3 : `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`  #This will start SSH Agent
Step 4 : `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`  #Add the SSH Key to the SSH Agent
Step 5 : `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | xclip -sel clip` #Copy the SSH Key to the Clipboard:Then go to github and paste it

Comment: Basically just quotes the GitHub instructions.